# How to watch AWS S3 files for deletion using Spring Integration Flow

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, spring-integration

I need to keep local file system in sync with remote file system (S3).

I have a lot of instances running my app so when a file is created in S3 I download it to my local file system. I have done it already.

Now I need to delete local files in all instances if it is deleted on S3. So I want to watch/listen to file deletions on S3.

How can I do it using Spring AWS Integration?

Comment: You can write a lambda function to listen S3 "delete" event and call your call with the deleted file information. Isn't it how you are tracking "add" event?

Comment: @Nambari do you have a snippet? Are you using SQS? Thank you very much!

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-event-notification/  and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html, though these links referring "Create", you could substitute "Create" with "Delete", other than that steps will be same. Example Lambda Python syntax: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html